# How to remove symbol in django [<Project:projectname>]

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
def passAuthProjFeature(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            author_name = request.POST['author_id']
            project_id = request.POST['tcgproject_id']
            feature_name = request.POST['tcgsearch_id']
            project_name =Project.objects.filter(id=project_id)

            project_name=str(project_name)
            project_name =  project_name.split[" "][1]
            project_name =  project_name.split[">"][0]
```

**when i print project name it gives me in** []
I want only projectname in variable

Comment: [<Project:ARA>] from this string I want only ARA string .
what to write in views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get instance of Project class, but it seems that you need only one field of instance, for example 'name'. You can get this:

```
project = Project.objects.values('name').get(id=project_id)
project_name = project['name']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
project_name =Project.objects.filter(id=project_id)
```

As you are using filter() method in the ORM query, it is returning the list of project objects.

I think better is to use the get() method in the query to get the desired result.

Assuming the below the model structure:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=any numeric value)
    ......
```

Try this query:

```
project_name = Project.objects.get(id=project_id).name
```